# Terraform: cannot provision aws ecs autoscaling cluster

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We use Terraform to provision an AWS Autoscaling Group and ECS Cluster. We decided to add a capacity provider to the ECS cluster and allow that to manage our scaling, as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html

But when we added the capacity provider resource and connected it to the cluster via the `capacity_providers` attribute on the cluster resource, `terraform plan` started complaining about a "Cylce". I'm not sure how else to configure this - it seems like every "connection" between the resources is setup correctly, and yet it seems terraform cannot provision this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name               = "${var.environment}_cluster"
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.capacity_provider.name]
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "capacity_provider" {
  name = "${var.environment}_capacity_provider"

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling_group.arn
    managed_termination_protection = "ENABLED"

    managed_scaling {
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 1
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_configuration" {
  name_prefix                 = "${var.environment}_launch_configuration-"
  image_id                    = data.aws_ami.ecs_os.id
  instance_type               = var.cluster_instance_type
  iam_instance_profile        = var.ecs_instance_profile
  security_groups             = var.security_groups["ecs_tasks"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.ssh_access.key_name
  user_data                   = data.template_file.launch_user_data.rendered

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "template_file" "launch_user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/taskdefs/user_data")}"

  vars = {
    ecs_cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
    efs_id      = var.efs_id
    aws_region  = data.aws_region.current.name
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling_group" {
  name                  = "${var.environment}_asg"
  max_size              = 4
  min_size              = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier   = [var.public_subnet_id]
  launch_configuration  = aws_launch_configuration.launch_configuration.name
  health_check_type     = "EC2"
  protect_from_scale_in = true
}
```

`terraform plan` output:

```
Error: Cycle: module.compute.aws_ecs_cluster.cluster, module.compute.data.template_file.launch_user_data, module.compute.aws_launch_configuration.launch_configuration, module.compute.aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling_group, module.compute.aws_ecs_capacity_provider.capacity_provider
```

Edit: to be clear: I understand that there is in fact a cycle. My question is how is it possible to have terraform provision this without having a cycle? I can't see how that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can define the name of the cluster like this.

```
locals {
  cluster_name = "${var.environment}_cluster"
}
```

And then

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name               = local.cluster_name
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.capacity_provider.name]
}

data "template_file" "launch_user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/taskdefs/user_data")}"

  vars = {
    ecs_cluster = local.cluster_name
    efs_id      = var.efs_id
    aws_region  = data.aws_region.current.name
  }
}
```

This will avoid the cycle.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote - you're absolutely right. The only problem was a dependency cycle in the names. By using locals to define the name of just one resource in the cycle, it breaks the cycle and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this before too but ended up not using capacity providers.

If you go into the AWS ECS web console, it appears the only place to create a capacity provider manually is INSIDE AN EXISTING CLUSTER. It doesn't seem to be a separate resource inside AWS but a sub-resource of a cluster. This is the real chicken-and-egg problem I think.

I think there would need to be a way to have terraform create the cluster (without the capacity provider), THEN create the capacity provider, and then finally assign it to the cluster. Smells like a bug report.

Comment: See the accepted answer - the only issue with the cycle is the names. Once that's sorted, the cycle is broken. Hopefully it helps you, too!